# Error : Could not write JSON: Class java.util.ArrayList not subtype of map - Serialiation to JSON in Spring Application

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm getting an error while sending `List<List<LinkedHashMap<String, MyDTO>>>` , it throws JSON parse exception. I've seen the same question in StackOverflow but there is no proper answer or maybe bcz the question wasn't detailed enough.

Error : `Could not write JSON: Class java.util.ArrayList not subtype of [map type; class java.util.LinkedHashMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class com.MyDTO]];`

Basically, what I want is to convert LinkedHashMap to JSON, but the order is getting changed (tried with both HashMap & LinkedHashMap - JSON treats both as Map and so order issue still persists). To fix it what I'm trying now is to store each map entry into a separate List (`List<LinkedHashMap<String, MyDTO>`) and then storing these lists inside a single list i.e. `List<List<LinkedHashMap<String, MyDTO>>`.
Screenshot -
[Screenshot of java data which is not converting to JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfy9R.png)

Here, the key is a String object & value is a DTO file.

**From the java side, everything is OK** but **facing issue in serialization using Jackson in the spring application**
 (response converted by @RestController) it throws the error.

I'm using a RESTful web service using Spring Framework where everything is fine except this part.

Pls, tell me how do I fix it and don't mention any links to some other questions that are unanswered or to learn the whole topic as I've searched everywhere for similar questions and still confused?

Answer (score -1):

You should be using `TypeReference` to resolve this issue like this:

```
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();

List<List<LinkedHashMap<String, MyDTO>>> obj = new ArrayList<>();
LinkedHashMap<String, MyDTO> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, MyDTO>();
MyDTO myd = new MyDTO("abc");
map.put("a1", myd);
map.put("a2", new MyDTO("def"));
List<LinkedHashMap<String, MyDTO>> list = Arrays.asList(map);
obj.add(list);
// serialization succeeded
String json = m.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);
System.out.println(json);

// deserialization succeeded        
ArrayList<ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, MyDTO>>> o = m.readValue(json, new TypeReference<ArrayList<ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, MyDTO>>>>(){});

System.out.println(o);

// output
[ [ {
  "a1" : {
    "name" : "abc"
  },
  "a2" : {
    "name" : "def"
  }
} ] ]

[[{a1=MyDTO [name=abc], a2=MyDTO [name=def]}]]
```

Sample DTO class:

```
public class MyDTO {
    private String name;

    public MyDTO() {}

    public MyDTO(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyDTO [name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```